# Find value of last non blank cell in a row (while skipping specific columns)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So basically I have a list of data in a row. They are totaled weekly statistics numbers and at the end of every month, there is a "total" column. The column where the 8 is at is where this formula will go and the column with the 5 and 0 in it is where my data starts. The grey columns are the "total" columns.

[image]

I am trying to use this code `=INDEX(J15:BT15,1,COUNT(J15:BT15))` to get the value of the last non-blank row. It doesn't work because the "total" column automatically populates as a sum of the weeks in that month for a "Month to date" kind of total. How would I go about skipping these "total" columns with the index formula, and if it isn't possible, how can I achieve this in a different way without relocating my data with formulas? Is there a way to do this with `=query()` by skipping columns with the header "total"? Very amateur at this so thank you in advance!

Comment: your question is highly ununderstandable from 2nd sentence to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EXAMPLE 1:

**`=INDEX({A1,B1,D1},MAX(({A1,B1,D1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)))`**

[image: 5]

- **`{A1,B1,D1}`** - included columns
- **`COLUMN(A1:C1)`** - full range (A1:D1) of columns (4 columns) minus excluded column (1) = A1:C1 (because 4 - 1 = 3)

---

### EXAMPLE 2:

**`=INDEX({A1,B1,D1,E1,F1,I1},MAX(({A1,B1,D1,E1,F1,I1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:F1)))`**

[image: 9]

- excluded columns: **`C, G, H`**
- **`COLUMN(A1:F1)`** = range **`A1:I1`** minus **3** excluded columns

---

### EXAMPLE 3:

**`=INDEX({J1,K1,M1},MAX(({J1,K1,M1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)))`**

[image: 4]

Comment: So I tried using what your comment as a template and I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? The formula I typed wasn't for the full range I wanted it to, but I decreased the range to eliminate error but I had no luck. https://gyazo.com/8f052b93c39b072a8c5e890698da7215

Comment: @TheMrIggs **`=INDEX({J1,K1,M1},MAX(({J1,K1,M1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)))`**

Comment: Works like a charm! How would I get the 2nd to last non blank using this formula?

Comment: So the formula you provided allows me to skip the totaling columns AND get the last non blank cell in row, as shown in example 3. How would I get the second to last non blank cell in a row using that formula? So how would I get the value of 3 (in the cell K1) in Example 3?

Comment: @TheMrIggs I see, try: **`=INDEX({J1,K1,M1},MAX(({J1,K1,M1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)-1))`**

Comment: This is perfect! I want to do this all the way up to 4th to last and that is self explanatory. However, since we are only on the 2nd week of the year, anything that is 3 weeks or more gives a reference error because it says it cant overwrite the cell directly to the right of it. How can I fix this? I tried this but it still returns the same error for some reason: `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX({J1,K1,M1},MAX(({J1,K1,M1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)-1))),"Error", INDEX({J1,K1,M1},MAX(({J1,K1,M1}<>"")*COLUMN(A1:C1)-1)))`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d57d5d56259a10dd5e7c603e0df62d05 I can't copy the single sheet because it uses automation from multiple sheets and everything wouldn't work. As you can see from the screenshot, the "No" to the right of the reference column is the last non blank cell in the row. The REF# cell is the one with the formula for second to last, but as you can see, there is no other value in that row as of now except one entry of "No" so it returns an error. Which is why I don't understand why the ISERROR function isn't working.

Comment: Try this. The formula works except not if it will land on column L. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bOk-286V19t7roUlIciZRYcR1vWkmxZ4Xsp_s0wQr5M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TheMrIggs I see now. you need to put everything into index of 1,1. check  **F5** now

Comment: Ah okay but there is only one value of "No" in that row and the F5 shows "No" as well?

Comment: You my friend are a LEGEND. I cannot thank you enough. With the dates listed at the top, they are actual dates but are conditionally formatted to just show the day number and the ending (th, nd, rd, st, etc.). So the automation you did only pulls the conditionally formatted version which doesn't make it all the way to the end goal. I see if I put another cell equal to the conditionally formatted date cells, it does the same thing. How could we make it so it equals the actual value of the date cell to get the actual date rather than "1st" or "3rd"?

Comment: EDIT: I see you we're referencing another tab so you may have not finished what you were trying to do. I notice there is a mismatch with the date automation and the data automation when there is less than 4 weeks filled out as well. I will be back to working on this tomorrow but I greatly appreciate the help and any further help onward.

Comment: And I don't know where the H column came from but if I delete it, the last 4 weeks data automation screws up for some reason and I don't know why.